# Re-Initialize RAID-0 in software after card failure

Tags: storage, software-raid, raid-0

I'm working on a Friend's WD MyBook "1TB" HDD that is not mounting.  When I got in to it, I discovered that it is really 2 500GB HDD's set up as RAID-0.  It appears that the drives themselves are fine, but that the logic board has failed.

My questions is this: can I re-initialize the RAID-0 using software RAID so that I can recover the data to another drive?  If so, how and which software RAID would be best (Preferably open source.  any platform OK).

Comment: Have you tried calling Western Digital's tech support?  They may have some good ideas.

Comment: Not yet.  Their working hours haven't corresponded with my work on the problem.

Comment: Another reason Raid 0 is a bad idea. I hope you get your data. Are you sure it is not Raid 1 (mirror)?

Answer (score 0):

Prospects are not good. *By far* your best best is to find a new logic board and mount the drives in that, and then you MIGHT get access to your data. It is also possible, though very unlikely, that the meta-data format used by the hardware is actually a software RAID format that's recognizable by something. Hardware RAID uses a variety of metadata formats that is exceedingly rarely interchangeable outside of the vendor's hardware. Or even within their hardware.

Your best bet is to find a replacement for the logic board.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible, the key feature you'll want to look for is to Import the configuration from the drives. If you try to set up a new RAID array without importing from the drives, you'll probably lose all your data.

Alternatively, you could seek the assistance of a magenetic recovery company for about $1000.